# why do I get formdata is read-only warning when trying to clear the formdata in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, multipartform-data

Im trying to send formdata to an api by using Axios. When the user gets an error after sending the request, the formdata should be cleared. But I got `Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: "formdata" is read-only` when trying to clear the data in formdata.

```js
    const formdata = new FormData();
    const fetchData = () => {
        allImage.forEach((file) => {
            formdata.append('files[]', file);
        });
        axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: URL,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': "multipart/form-data", 
            },
            data: formdata,
        }).then(function (result) { 
            if(result.data.message === "Receipt Successfully added") {
                Alert.alert("Upload Successufull", result.data.message);
                navigation.goBack()
            }

        }).catch(function (error) {
            if(error.response.status == 413) {
                Alert.alert("Error", "The attached file(s) is too large.")
                formdata = new FormData();
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FormData is a constant, it should be a let